# Self updating calulated fields

Tags: excel, self, updating

This might sound pretty basic but I'm stuck and unsure of how to formulate my query in search engines.

You can see the simple table I have in the picture. These are ratios, so for example 475 units of Mazout are equivalent to 1 unit of Granules de bois, 725 units of propane, etc.
What I want is to be able to enter X amount in any of the Quantité équivalente row (single cell) and have all the others update to the proper ratio automatically.

So for example if I enter 825 units of propane, I want to know what the equivalent results would be in the other columns.

I hope that my problem is clear.

[image: What I have]

Answer (score 1):

If you type something in a cell, you remove whatever formula is in it. The solution is to input the data elsewhere.

First thing you will need is a lookup table with the various ratios, something like:

[image]

You will then need two cells for your input. One with a dropdown list for the fuel type and the other for typing in the quantity:

[image]

Finally, in `B2` of your table, use the following formula:

```
=IF(B1=$I2,$J2,$J2/INDEX($N2:$N6,MATCH($I2,$M2:$M6,0))*INDEX($N2:$N6,MATCH(B1,$M2:$M6,0)))
```

And populate the rest of the row.

Final result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can [mark the answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so everyone will know your question is answered